# Is it possible to change the value of a primary key of some Room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I tried to change the value of a primary key in Room using @Update query, but it works only for "non-primary key columns". Now I'm curious, is it possible to change it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary-Key should be unique. So, once its generated and assigned to a row, then you can't change it. Please check from [here][1].

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035080/edit-primary-key#:~:text=As%20a%20general%20rule%2C%20you,but%20depending%20on%20the%20skew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035080/edit-primary-key#:%7E:text=As%20a%20general%20rule%2C%20you,but%20depending%20on%20the%20skew)).